# how to use ajax to show notification data that are stored in data variable

Tags: php, ajax, synchronization

I have counted the number of unread message and put in $cntUnread variable.
it need to refresh to show the sync message.
i want to show that variable sync automatically without refreshing whole page.

```
 <li><a href="#" class="settings dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i
 class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="badge bg-pink"><?php echo $cntUnread ?></span></a></li>
```

ajax code:
i have just tried these two method, because i don't know how to do.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".submit").onclick(function(){
        $('.badge').load('<? echo $cntUnread ?>');
    });
});
</script>
```

i want to show the message too sync automatically.
when other user sends mail then the count of unread message and unread message in inbox must be shown.

Comment: Try SSH tunneling/Websockets.

Comment: try using ajax and call that ajax after few seconds..:)